# Adding tables/stored procedures with aspnet_regsql

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider

I have got an established database, (attached mdf file) called Speakom. I Executed this statement.

> aspnet_regsql -S (local)\SQLEXPRESS -E -A all -d Speakom

I got a messaage stating that it added the following features: Membership, Profile, Rolemanager, etc..

The question is where has it added them, cause I dont see them in the server explorer.

I have my own User table, which key I could connect with the membership key from the membership table.. i.e. connect primary key from membership table to foreign key in my established table..

Problem is that I dont see the membership table1?!?

**UPDATE**
Now that it is clear.. how do I see my datbase tables through visual studio...I installed the membership table.. in the same databse but I cant see it..

I added a connection to this path:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\dddddddddddd\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\SpeakomSite\SpeakomSite\App_Data\Speakom.mdf
```

But I still see no password, user, tables :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look for the ASP.NET Configuration Icon located at the top of the solution explorer.  This will navigate you to the ASP.NET Configuration page where you can customize Membership, Role and Profile information.  Alternatively you could goto:   http://localhost:YourPort/asp.netwebadminfiles/security/security.aspx

You could also check if they are also stored at the SQL backend by logging into SQL Server Management Studio, connect to your SQL Express instance and then Security which contains additional Role information.

Comment: So I can add users through WAT to add users and then add them authomatically. How do I connect between the membership table and my Users table?

Comment: I have got SQL Express 2008 installed on VS2010. I cant logon to management studio..cause I dont have one.. And as I remember, I cant install one..cause it will have a conflict